# boost::thread_resource_error

Tags: bitcoind

I am getting this error in the debug.log of bitcoind:

EXCEPTION: N5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_21thread_resource_errorEEEEE
boost::thread_resource_error

It happens every 2 to 4 hours, and I need to restart bitcoind.

What I do is I request recent transactions every 2 seconds, via json-rpc.

Does anybody else got this error? Is there a way of avoiding this error?

**UPDATE:**

I actually managed to figure out it is related to calling *walletlock*. Whenever *walletlock* is called (via json-rpc or command line, doesn't matter), a new thread is spawned and it doesn't die. Looks like a bug.

Comment: What is the exact RPC call you issue? `listtransactions`?

Comment: I actually managed to figure out it related to calling walletlock. Whenever walletlock is called (via json-rpc or command line, doesn't matter), a new thread is spawned and it doesn't die. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an [error from the Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/boost/thread_resource_error.html) that is thrown "thread-related resources cannot be acquired". You probably should contact the dev team about this error, from your description it appears to be a memory leak.

Comment: It seems like the problem is the walletlock method of the API.
Whenever it is called, a new thread is created and it doesn't die. Do you know where I can report this bug?

Comment: I`d submit it either here https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=4.0 or here https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues or email the devs. Probably the second option is the best.